# how to get the thumbnails of a mp3 file in listview in android

Tags: android

I want to get the thumbnails of the mp3 file in listview with the title track in android I have done lot but I didn't get the appropriate ans please give me the correct answer

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438809/how-do-i-get-album-thumbnails-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The [myid3](http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/) Library is a good java library for reading and writing id3-Tags. With it you can extract the id3-Pictures.
I haven't tested it on Android though, but at least you can give it a try.