# Get cover picture by song

Tags: android, media-player, mediastore

Is it possible to get a cover picture by song and not by album.
Because I have one self combined album with songs and they all have different cover pictures.
But when I want to query them I always get the same picture returned.

```
String[] ARG_STRING = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
...
String albumCover = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
...
MusicUtils.getArtwork(this, -1, Integer.parseInt(albumID));
```

So i would like to know how it's possible to get an cover image of an song.

I know MusicUtils supports getArtwork by SongId, but what ID should I use because  MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID is not working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `MusicUtils`, however, you should be able to get the cover art from the file itself by using `MediaMetadataRetriever`. Here is a brief code snippet showing how to use it. The uri referenced is the content uri for the file you want to retrieve the art for.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
byte[] rawArt;
Bitmap art;
BitmapFactory.Options bfo=new BitmapFactory.Options();

mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

// if rawArt is null then no cover art is embedded in the file or is not 
// recognized as such.
if (null != rawArt) 
    art = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);

// Code that uses the cover art retrieved below.
```

Comment: @MartinMetselaar where yu are getting image uri an song..?? how to get image uri an song..?

Comment: I guess that maybe the URI was built in the way that's quoted in this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438809/997940