# How to get thumbnails of audio files by using MediaStore

Tags: android, media-player, mediastore

I am now working on a simple music player and i need to get the thumbnail art of all audio files.

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR
    };
    cursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

        name.add(cursor.getString(4));
        path.add(cursor.getString(3));
        duration.add(cursor.getString(5));
    }
```

how can i get it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display Album Art using MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM\_ART?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573972/how-can-i-display-album-art-using-mediastore-audio-albums-album-art)

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein I appreciate that you found a better answered question. But this question is asked before your suggested one. Check the asked date.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314617/get-cover-picture-by-song/16972099#16972099) I gave on a similar issue. You will need to give the `Uri` of the song you to get the cover art on.

Comment: he asked about `MediaStore`, not `MediaMetadataRetriever`

Comment: @user924 `MediaMetadataRetriever` is how you access the album art.

Comment: `MediaMetadataRetriever` is used to get picture directly from audio file (.mp3) which is slow. Android does it for us periodically, so it has Mediastore library from which we can get info and I suppose thumbnail of audio files. I mean author didn't ask general question about how to get thumbnail he asked how to get it using MediaStore

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils#createAudioThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20int)), it should be:

```
Bitmap image = ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail("your file name", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

This might work for you. (Though it crashes with a `NoSuchMethodError` in Marshmellow).