# How to get album image of a song in android?

Tags: android

Hy Friends.
I want to get album image of songs. But I don't know how to get it.
Please Help me.

This is my code where I retrieve all the songs title and duration of songs from my sd card.

```
public List<SongDetails> getSongList(Context context)
{
    ContentResolver musicResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri , null , null , null , null);
    songDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

    if(musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            SongDetails songDetails = new SongDetails();
            songDetails.setSongTitle(musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

            String songDuration = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

            if(String.valueOf(songDuration) != null){
                try{
                    Long time = Long.valueOf(songDuration);
                    long seconds = time/1000;
                    long minutes = seconds/60;
                    seconds = seconds % 60;

                    if(seconds<10){
                        String csongs_duration = String.valueOf(minutes) + ":0" + String.valueOf(seconds);
                        songDetails.setSongDuration(csongs_duration);
                    }else{
                        String ccsongs_duration = String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds);
                        songDetails.setSongDuration(ccsongs_duration);
                    }
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                }
            }else{
                String nothing = "0";
                songDetails.setSongDuration(nothing);
            }
            songDetailsList.add(songDetails);
        }while(musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return songDetailsList;
}
```

Know I want to get image of that particular song.

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438809/how-do-i-get-album-thumbnails-in-android)? This might be useful.

Comment: It's not working dear... :(

Comment: you can try solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314617/get-cover-picture-by-song

Comment: Thanks.... it's work for me....